# Is there any error bound theory for a Derivative Estimator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation, finite-differences

Given *f(x)* $\in$ $C^1(\Omega)$ and a finite set of samples $\{x_s\} \in \Omega$, one wants to estimate $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ at ${x_s}$, by finite difference or other methods. An intuitive idea is that the best quality of estimation should depend on the given function $f$ and the samples $x_s$ which means no matter what method is applied one shouldn't expect an estimation better than this bound. Do we have a theory on such bound yet? Or conversely, given an estimation $\widehat{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}$, is it possible to determine whether or not it is an optimal estimation?

Comment: In the case where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$, if your approximation is linear, you can get exact error formulas and asymptotic error formulas using Taylor's theorem, assuming your $f$ is sufficiently differentiable.

Comment: You are using the words bound and estimate as if they are interchangeable. They are not. What do you really want? What is optimal in your context? Maximal accuracy given the data?